# Order By with OrientDB & GremlinPipe

Tags: java, orientdb, gremlin

I'm trying to order my vertices according to a property "age"

Here is my code so far. I'm using OrientDB inside Java and the GremlinPipe framework.

```
new GremlinPipeline<Object, Object>(graphDb.getVertices())
                                .has("calculated",false).has("weight", Compare.NOT_EQUAL, Integer.MAX_VALUE)
                                .order(new PipeFunction<Pair<Vertex, Vertex>, Integer>() {
                                    public Integer compute(Pair<Vertex, Vertex> argument) {
                                        return ((Integer) argument.getA().getProperty("age")).compareTo((int) argument.getB().getProperty("age"));
                                    } 
                                }).range(0, 0);
```

I'm getting the error :
 *The method order(TransformPipe.Order) in the type GremlinPipeline is not applicable for the arguments (new 
 PipeFunction,Integer>(){})*

However if a want to order the neighbors of a vertex, this method is working perfectly fine

```
new GremlinPipeline<Object, Object>(graphDb.getVertices("Person.name", testValues.get(i)))
                                           .outE("knows").inV()
                                          .order(new PipeFunction<Pair<Vertex, Vertex>, Integer>() { 
                public Integer compute(Pair<Vertex, Vertex> argument) {
                    return ((Integer) argument.getA().getProperty("age")).compareTo((int) argument.getB().getProperty("age"));
                }});
```

Comment: Hi, how is it your structure (class/properties) ?

Comment: hi, for the vertex : a class named Person with properties : calculated, weight and age. For the edge : class called knows